# Talend Api : How to extract the Engine Logs from talend cloud

Tags: etl, talend, data-integration

I am trying to extract the logs from talend cloud, I started by extracting the execution logs of each task, but knowing that those logs are too long and storing them would take too much space I am working on extracting the logs of the corresponding engines instead.

I used this request to get the runtimeId:

Method GET:
`https://api.<env>.cloud.talend.com/processing/runtimes/remote-engines/`

Followed by this request to get the logs:
Method GET:
`https://api.<env>.cloud.talend.com/monitoring/executions/{runId}logs`
-> this is the request I used to get the logs of each execution of a specific task using the `executionId` in the field `{runId}` but when I tried to put in the same field, the `runtimeId` corresponding to a specific engine hoping I would get the engine's logs, I got a 404 response:

> "execution not found"

Talend Api documentation:
https://api.talend.com/apis/
https://api.talend.com/use-cases/monitoring-tasks/monitor-task-runs-with-only-relevant-logs/